# Using a value instead of variable in the html for a directive attribute

Tags: angularjs

I want to use a [directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) that have an attribute. I want this attribute to always be true, so I do not need a scope variable for this. But I am pretty sure that the following is wrong, it is probably a scope variable named true instead of the boolean value true. How should this write what I want?

```
<accordion close-others="true">
</accordion>
```

**Edit:** I realized that this was a bad example. What if I have an attribute which I want to give the value "someText". How can I make the difference between the value "someText" and some variable named "someText"? Like this:

```
<some-directive some-attribute="someText"></some-directive>
```

Comment: should work fine the way you have it, if not create demo that isn't doing as expected

Comment: How can I change between using the boolean value true and and a variable named true? Does Angular first check if there is a variable named true and if not then treat it as a value?

Comment: Oh, I just realized, it is probably not allowed to call a variable "true"... Sorry for the stupid question!

Comment: I updated the question with a less stupid variant...

Comment: did you try using single quotes to make it a string? Since html is showing a boolean, question is less clear now with edit

Comment: Added an example for my new case. So you mean I can specify the value like this ...some-attribute="'someText'"...? That sound reasonable. If that is correct, then formulate that as an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: can also use `@` instead of `=` if you are creating isolated scope directive. Or you can get any attribute value within `link` function. Your overall issue is just not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define in your directive how angular should handle that attribute value.

This means it will be parsed as regular javascript if you define it like this:

```
scope: {
    closeOthers: '='
}

//gives you in scope.closeOthers:
<e close-others="true" /> //true
<e close-others="'someText'" /> //someText
<e close-others="variableName" /> //contentOfVariableName
```

What you actually want is to parse it as string attribute (string with embedded interpolation expressions) like this:

```
scope: {
    closeOthers: '@'
}

//gives you in scope.closeOthers:
<e close-others="true" /> //true
<e close-others="'someText'" /> //'someText'
<e close-others="variableName" /> //variableName
<e close-others="prefix/{{variableName}}" /> //prefix/contentOfVariableName
```

`scope: {}`creates a new isolated scope. I don't personally like those isolated scopes and prefer to create a normal sub scope with `scope: true` and watch or parse attribute values on my own:

```js
.directive('e', ['$interpolate', function($interpolate) {
     return {
         restrict: 'E',
         scope: true,
         link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
             attributes.$observe('closeOthers', function(value) {
                 if ('true' === value.toLowerCase()) {
                      // ...
                 }
             });

             //or if you don't need a watcher, which I prefer sometimes, because it's not always needed and costs performance
             var value = $interpolate(attributes.closeOthers)(scope.$parent);
             if ('true' === value.toLowerCase()) {
                 ///...
             }
         }
     }
});
```

You said `I want this attribute to always be true, so I do not need a scope variable for this`, so I guess you don't even need to parse it (if you don't care about {{}} expressions). Then you can simply do:

```js
link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
    var closeOthers = 'closeOthers' in attributes; //true or false
}
```

Which allows you to use 'close-others' like this:

```xml
<accordion close-others></accordion>
<accordion close-others="true"></accordion>
```

Comment: Wow, this was a much more detailed than I was expecting, and an answer that I learned a lot from! Thanks a lot @MArc :)